# c++ - finding sum and products of elements in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm quite new to c++ and I'm having trouble with this.
It shows the correct sum but the product isn't.

The user specifies how many numbers they'll enter, enters the numbers, the program then prints out the sum and product of all the numbers entered.

What seems to be its problem?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int arr[20],i,n,sum=0,product=0;
cout<<"How many elements you want to enter?: ";
cin>>n;


cout << "Please enter " << n << " values to find their sum and product" <<endl;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
cin >> arr[i];
cout << "value #" << i << ": " << arr[i] << " entered." << endl;
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
sum=sum+arr[i];
}

 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
 product=product*arr[i];
}
cout<<"Sum is "<<sum<<endl;
cout<<"Product is "<<product;



 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to flag this as a homework assignment if that's what it is. Also, you really need to specify what outputs you're getting for what inputs if you want people to take the time to help you.

Comment: You can definitely put the product and sum calculation in the same loop. Spare some CPU time ;)

Comment: You should add a condition to your loop if(i==0){product=arr[i];}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a simple mathematical error. You declared the `product` variable to 0, anything multiplied by 0 is equivalent to 0, if you change the value of `product` to 1, it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, you your mistake is that you initialize the product with 0.
Besides, here is an "elegant" way to add and multiply elements of array using c++ algorithms:

```
#include<functional>
#include<numeric>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   vector<int> nums = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
   vector<int> sums(nums.size(), 0);
   vector<int>products(nums.size());
   std::partial_sum(nums.begin(), nums.end(), sums.begin());
   std::partial_sum(nums.begin(), nums.end(), products.begin(), std::multiplies<int>());
}
```

Now the elements of vector `sums` contain the running sum of the `nums` vector:
1, 3, 6 ,10, 15
And the elements of `products` vector contain running products:
1, 2, 6, 24, 120